# Adding new column to existing table with default value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

Suppose I have a table called `SerialNumbers` which has columns:

- Id `(int)`
- SerialNumber `(nvarchar)`
- IsValid `(bit)`
- ToBeUsedBy `(DateTime)`

Currently this table is being used by numerous different applications. Now we have a requirement to add a new column named `CurrentlyAt (int)` which will always have a default value of `1`. I have gone ahead and added the column with a default value of `1`.

So my question is, would I now have to change all my previous `insert` queries to include the new column or would it add a value by default if I didn't add it to the old `insert` statements?

Comment: You can omit  the new field on your insert query

Comment: What would be the point of having a default if you were required to always supply a value anyway? ...no wait, that's a silly question because that's actually exactly how T-SQL default function parameters work (if you want the default, you *still* have to pass the parameter, but you can use `default`). Fortunately for `INSERT` statements the approach that's not useless prevails, and you're not required to mention the column at all.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Only one of the applications should be updating the value the rest do not need to supply it. The idea is when an entry is added to the table from any of the apps the default value is insert but when I try the sql query falls over because of the newly added column

Comment: You have to make the column NOT NULL for the default value to get populated if you don't specify the column in the insert. If you don't make the column NOT NULL it will just be NULL when the column is not in the insert statement.

Comment: @SeanLange: no, that's not how it works. Minimal repro: `CREATE TABLE T(ID INT, X BIT NULL DEFAULT 0); INSERT T(ID) VALUES (1); SELECT * FROM T`. You may be thinking of ORMs like Entity Framework who may get confused and retrieve the column for purposes of generating a statement, but without retrieving the default from the constraint (and so unwittingly pass an explicit `NULL` when the user did not intend it).

Comment: @SeanLange It is marked as `NOT NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, of course, is that it depends.

As long as your existing `INSERT` statements have an explicit column list, you don't need to edit them, and the default value will be inserted, well, by default.

```
INSERT INTO SerialNumbers (
  Id,
  SerialNumber,
  IsValid,
  ToBeUsedBy)
SELECT....
```

**BUT** if you have any inserts that *do not* have a column list, they'll throw an error:

```
INSERT INTO SerialNumbers 
SELECT....
```

Because the number of columns in the `SELECT`, or `VALUES` clause perhaps, will no longer match the number of columns in the `INSERT` target table.

The solution there is to add the explicit column list, and then to get in the habit of always using said list, for this very reason.

**EDIT:** To Sean Lange's point, I was assuming the new column was `NOT NULL`. If it's nullable, then yes, there are more possible outcomes, which are likely to generate outcomes that are not as expected.

Comment: That makes sense